# HTML , Select Option Content Align

Tags: html, css

basically what I'm trying to accomplish here is the following :

Given the fact that normally the  options under select in html are under a dropdown , for example :

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

What I want to accomplish here is moving those options out of the dropdown and having them visible & aligned horizontally .

Also it would help a lot if you can help me on adding a small image above each option title

Thank you so much and apologies for my broken English !

Comment: You will need to build your own component for this, it is not possible with the built-in select element. I would start with some radio buttons with custom styling if you want single-selection options that are always visible.

Comment: @DBS , which part is not doable here?

Comment: You can't make a `select` element display it's options all the time, and I don't believe you can display them horizontally either.

Comment: @DBS http://jsfiddle.net/rjmnmcru/ , check this one out , looks like a good start

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly:

I'm not sure it's possible to do what you're aiming with a `select` element, however you can use radio buttons to do something similar, here's an example:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* This prevents users highlighting the text, but still allows it to be clicked */
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Select the next label after the checked input and apply the "selected" style */

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  color: #FFF;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Cars:

<input type="radio" name="cars" value="volvo" id="cars-volvo" />
<label for="cars-volvo">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/" />
  Volvo
</label>

<input type="radio" name="cars" value="saab" id="cars-saab" />
<label for="cars-saab">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/" />
  Saab
</label>

<input type="radio" name="cars" value="opel" id="cars-opel" />
<label for="cars-opel">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/" />
  Opel
</label>

<input type="radio" name="cars" value="audi" id="cars-audi" />
<label for="cars-audi">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/" />
  Audi
</label>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your input here , any idea on how I can add an icon on top of each title ?

Comment: @Mike I've updated the answer with some small images in the options.

Comment: @Mike it helps when you vote and accept an answer you admit